# BigQuery superfluous remote function execution in batches

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I have a table in BigQuery with two columns id (integer) and data (string).
I also have a UDF calling a remote function in CloudRun. The CloudRun function has
Maximum number of instances limit set to 10.
The UDF calc_udf function takes string argument and generates a number. It is implemented according to [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/remote-functions#:%7E:text=A%20BigQuery%20remote%20function%20allows,in%20BigQuery%20user%2Ddefined%20functions.) documentation, meaning that the function can handle batches of input data.
The calc_udf function has max_batching_rows = 1000 defined in the options section.

If I execute the following query:

```
SELECT id, TestData.calc_udf(data) AS calc_val FROM TestData.mydataset where id < 100000 limit 100;
```

I noticed that CloudRun remote function is called multiple times (13 times) with the payload containing 100 data points.
This seems to be a superfluous operation since the calc_udf could be called only once with 100 data points.
How can I avoid these extra calls?

My main goal is to update my table values using an external calculation.

I have tried the following statement:

```
UPDATE TestData.mydataset SET calculated_value = TestData.calc_udf(data) where TRUE ;
```

I find that TestData.calc_udf(data) is called for each row, without using any batches for data values.

After this point I started to experiment to be able to use my calc_udf function in batches. I found that, with the provided query I can execute the calculation in batches, but then I face with superfluous CloudRun usage.